# Wrong color in toolbar items MaterialButton on Api 21

Tags: java, android, api, button, colors

I have a few Material buttons as ActionMenuItem set on a toolbar in AppCompatActivity. The colors however are wrong only on Api 21 (Android 5).
[image: How it looks on Api >21]
[image: Api 21]
The other buttons are disabled but basically they should be blue but are red on Api 21.
 I'm setting the colors like this

```
 buttonAction.setBackgroundTintList(menuItem.getColor(context));
 buttonAction.setStrokeColor(menuItem.getColor(context));
 buttonAction.setTextColor(menuItem.getColor(context));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself. The problem was the default background was set with 
?attr/colorPrimary. I made new colors xml for API 21 and set it like this @color/colorPrimary. I don't know if it's the best fix. If anyone has a better answer please write it.